# Angular @types/bootstrap error: Namespace 'popper.js' has no exported member

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, popper.js

I've done a fair amount of searching and have been unable to come up with any guidance on an error - the one article I found seems to indicate that it may just be a version compatibility issue, but I am unsure of whether that's actually the case.

I have used `npm install @types/bootstrap`, along with its dependencies `@popper.js` and `@jquery`.  When I run `ng serve`, I get this error:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@types/bootstrap/index.d.ts(35,29): error TS2694: Namespace ''popper.js'' has no exported member 'Offset'.
```

Anyone have any insight into getting past this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting around this and compiling by going into the `node_moduls/@types/bootstrap/index.d.ts` file and replacing every errored 'popper.js' type with `any` and could at least compile and continue using the functionality without issue.